# How to create mouth

Tags: mesh

I create 3D meshs in Blender to import them to the 3D animation software Akeytsu. I need to create a mouth that open and close. A mouth that has teeth and cavity in it. How do you create a space in a mesh? How do you create a animation mouth? How do you fill a circle?[image]

In a animation a character has the mouth closed, mouth closed with teeth or open the mouth with teeth. You need a opening and how do you create it? The mouth got to be at the lowest part of the head. The teeth is put in the opening. This character has the mouth i got to create. https://www.nukeygara.com/akeyschool/getting-started/sky-surfer-character-demo It doesn't need to be as advanced but be similar to this mouth. You move the openings edges, hide and don't hide teeth. When a human open the mouth, it's something behind the teeth. How do you create it? What more is to say? You know how a mouth looks when a human is talking. I need a tutorial or other information to create such mouth.

Tell me how to do this other things so i don't need to post more threads. How do you see vertex paint of every part of the mesh? Now i see vertex paint of one part at a time in vertex paint mode but otherwise i don't see it. I added a circle and don't see it in solid mode. How do you make a circle you added to a mesh you see?

Comment: Hello your question is too broad, could you please show how your head looks like?

Comment: Hello, Rebourne ...We don't have enough to go on here. We definitely need a look a your existing mesh, and a clear indication of how you want your mouth to look. Please edit to include these details, then this question will be answerable, we'll re-open, and do our best for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need try shape keys to deform your character. To create mouth you can use sculpt Grab or Elastic Deform.